# How to retrieve Tower configuration from playbook?

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

In my playbook I setup the LDAP configuration with the [`awx.settings`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/index.html) module. So far so good.

To attend groups in AWX under `/Settings/LDAP Default/LDAP Team Map/` I need to retrieve the values from `LDAP_TEAM_MAP` and than attend a new value.

- Is there a way to read this value from a variable?
- Or is it a need to
  get the values from the AWX REST API

  ```
  https://{{ TOWER_URL }}/api/v2/settings/ldap/AUTH_LDAP_TEAM_MAP
  ```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

controller_api is the way it works!

```
---
- name: Load the UI settings specifying the connection info
  set_fact:
    controller_settings: "{{ lookup('awx.awx.tower_api', 'settings/ldap', 
              host='localhost', username='admin', password='password',
              verify_ssl=False) }}"

- name: debug
  debug:
     var: controller_settings["AUTH_LDAP_TEAM_MAP"]
```

Thx for support

Answer (score 0):

According Ansible Tower documentation [Launch a Job Template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#launch-a-job-template), that kind of information will not be added to the environment. Also the documentation of [`awx.awx`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/index.html) modules do not show an option for gathering the config directly.

Therefore the in the question mentioned [REST API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#) call will be necessary. For this a lookup plugin, [`controller_api`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/controller_api_lookup.html#ansible-collections-awx-awx-controller-api-lookup) is available also.

... currently there seems to be an error with the documentation import, therefore you may to have a [look into the plugin source directly](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/awx_collection/plugins/lookup/controller_api.py) for usage information.

**Further Reading**

- [Introducing the AWX collection](https://www.ansible.com/blog/introducing-the-awx-collection)
- [AWX Ansible Collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/awx/awx)

Comment: Thx for the hint for "controller_api".
Will have a new try tomorrow.