# Is there a way to set AWX Tower's: Azure AD OAuth2 Callback URL or Azure AD OAuth2 Key via an API call?

Tags: rest, ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-awx

Just wondering if there is any way I have not seen yet that is able to set Azure AD OAuth2 Key or Azure AD OAuth2 Callback URL via any type of API?

Answer (score 1):

You may first have a look into [Tower API Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/System_Configuration) and to get familiar with the Ansible Tower REST API. You could use calls like

```bash
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/auth/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .
curl --silent --user ${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD} https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/config/ --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" | jq .
```

and proceed further later with data structures and configuration updates.

**Further Q&A**

- [How to retrieve Tower configuration from playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195987/)